# PHP mysqli bind_param types

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I have the following:

```
$query = "select * from test_admin_users where school_id=? and username=?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("is", $school_id,$username);

$username='jones';
$school_id=11;

$stmt->execute();
```

Which works as expected. Being new to mysqli_ I played around with the bind_param types and found that

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $school_id,$username);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $school_id,$username);
```

Both also give the expected results. Why are incorrect types being accepted?

Also, is there any way to use an identifier such as *username* instead of *?* in the query template?

Thanks.

Comment: For named placeholders, you might want to take a look at PDO instead of mysqli.

Comment: For the first, `ss`, an integer can be a string, but a string cannot be an integer. That is why it works. For the 2nd, `11`. As those do not exist and are not legal flags, it then assumes it's a string, which falls back to `ss` like you had previously.

Comment: Opps, sorry, second exaample should be ii, not 11